# how to loop over an array of object and count how many repeating values exist?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, counter

Lets say I have a list of object with different keys, one of them is **name**.

```
var resulttemp = [{name: "HYD. CYLINDER"}, {name: "pelle"}, {name: "HYD. CYLINDER"}, {name: "1212"}, {name: "pelle"}]
```

The final result should be:

```
var uniquePartNamesWithCount = [{name: "HYD. CYLINDER", count: 2}, {name: "pelle", count: 2}, {name: "1212", count: 1}]
```

I know how to just push unique names to an array, but how do I manage to add a **counter**?

Comment: use `Array#reduce` method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to generate an object that will hold each name and the counter related to it. Finally, you can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get your desired array.

```js
var input = [
  {name: "HYD. CYLINDER"},
  {name: "pelle"},
  {name: "HYD. CYLINDER"},
  {name: "1212"},
  {name: "pelle"}
];

let res = input.reduce((acc, {name}) =>
{
    acc[name] = acc[name] || ({name, count: 0});
    acc[name].count++;
    return acc;    
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(res));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

If you need the final array sorted by the counter, then you can do:

```
console.log( Object.values(res).sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count) );
```

Answer (score 2):

This does what you're looking for:

```js
// Declarations
var resulttemp = [
  {name: "HYD. CYLINDER"},
  {name: "pelle"},
  {name: "HYD. CYLINDER"},
  {name: "1212"},
  {name: "pelle"}
];
const counts = {}
const uniquePartNamesWithCount = []

// Get sums
for (let obj of resulttemp){
  if(counts[obj.name]){ counts[obj.name]++;} 
  else{counts[obj.name] = 1 }
}

// Add objects to final array
const keys = Object.keys(counts);
for(let key of keys){
  let obj = {};
  obj[key] = counts[key];
  uniquePartNamesWithCount.push(obj);
}

// Print results
console.log(uniquePartNamesWithCount);
```